# Editing Share Point Input from Share point designer

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

Is there a way to edit/trim the data from the share point column that i will use on the share point designer.

The column is a email ID content is example.s.sample and i will use it as a greeting to a automatic email in my new workflow:

Like

TRIM (example.s.sample) to be just Example.

Hi Example,

Is there a way to edit it?

Answer (score 0):

Yep - there is no Split function in SPD workflows, but 2013 workflows offer enough utility actions that you can still do this. Here are the two steps to store this in a variable:

```
Find . in CurrentItem:EmailID (Output to Variable:intPeriodPlace)
then Copy Variable:intPeriodPlace characters from start of CurrentItem:EmailID (Output to Variable:strFirstName)
```

Then when you build your email, use the strFirstName variable and you're all set.

In case you aren't familiar with the workflow actions, the first one is "Find Substring in String" and the second one is "Extract Substring from Start of String" - both Utility Actions.

Hope this helps!